# Fancyhdr heading

Tags: header-footer

i am trying to get headers with the `fancyhdr` package. The only thing that is missing is actual header now. The header should mention the subsection because i dont have many sections but several subsections.

I am not quite sure whether i use "book" or "article" so it would be great if you could give 2 options: the header at the top left corner and for the book it should change from the left corner to the right corner. Anything else should stay like this (page number at the bottom, line under the headline)

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, german]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm,}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % <===============================================
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % <================================= page nummer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt} % <=================== no header rule
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=40mm,right=30mm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\newpage

\section{BBBTest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example code has no subsections! What is the header supposed to display in this case?

Comment: Yes sorry, that is because i really wanted to shorten the document. In that case i would want the header to display the section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don' know how to do that with `fancyhdr`, but it is very easy with `titleps`, from the `titlesec` bundle, which has tests to determine whether there is a chapter, section, subsection number at a given position in the document. Note that `titleps` and `fancyhdr` are incompatible. Here is a possibility:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, german]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm,}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{mine}{%
\setheadrule{1pt}\headrule
\sethead{\ifthesubsection{\thesubsection~\subsectiontitle}{\thesection~\sectiontitle}}{}{}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}

\pagestyle{mine}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=40mm,right=30mm, vmargin=2cm}

\begin{document}

\section{A First Section and No Subsection}
\newpage

\section{BBBTest}
\lipsum
\subsection{And Now the Long Awaited Subsection! }
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add the Section/Subsection Number in front of the header?

Comment: For the section, it is quite possible. Do you want only the section number, or prefixed with the chapter number? For the subsection number, that's a new requirement. Where should should it be? And what about the subsection title?

Comment: I dont use Chapters so only section and subsection would be good. I think it should be like 1.2 BBBTEST ?

Comment: Sorry, I messed up with a similar question (with chapters). Yes, of course, it's simple. Please see my updated answer if it befits you.

Comment: I just realized, that it is written "0 table of Content" in the headline at the table of content page. Can i somehow delete that "0" ?

Comment: Two questions: 1) is your table of contents on a separate page? 2) Do you really need to have ‘Table of Contents’ in the header of the first page of this table  of contents – from my point  of view, it would be a redundant information.

Comment: 1) Yes it is on a separate page 2) No i dont really need a header there, as i have "table of content" written above.

Comment: A question I had forgotten: does your table of contents fit on a single page?

Comment: Yes it does fit on one page.

Comment: In this case, just add  `\thispagestyle{plain}` just before `\tableofcontents`.